# Can not install SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, office-dev-pnp

I am trying to install "SharePoint Online Management Shell" when I do so got below error.

> This application requires the following to be installed:
>
> - PowerShell 3.0.

[image]

When I checked my Power Shell version its greater then 3.0

[image]

Comment: I believe this tool actually needs PS 3.0 to run, not just a minimum of 3.0. See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37663.sharepoint-online-how-to-install-management-shell.aspx

Comment: Thanks @user58700 can you please help me how can I install PS3.0

Comment: I would try installing Windows Management Framework 5.0 first. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395 
Then try running the installer again.

Comment: @user58700 WMF 5.0 RTM has been superseded by WMF 5.1. So try to install that and got "Update for Windows (KB3191566) is already installed on this computer." message.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to install the PowerShell 3.0 as it is required. You can download the [PowerShell 3.0 from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)

Once you install it then retry to install the SPO management shell. Also take a look here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31960.sharepoint-online-working-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks for helping but when I try to install this it says "The update is not applicable for your computer"

Comment: try to uninstall the current version of PowerShell and SPO powershell then install the power 3.0

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by uninstall current version of PowerShell. Do you have some link for instruction to remove. I removed "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell" with command "Uninstall-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Force"

Answer (score 0):

This article seems to address your exact issue:

https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000253824-enable-scripting-capabilities-with-powershell-for-office-365

It specifically states to Download and Install Windows Management Framework 5.1 if your error appears:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

After installing, run your SPO Management Shell installer again.

Comment: WMF 5.0 RTM has been superseded by WMF 5.1. So try to install that and got "Update for Windows (KB3191566) is already installed on this computer."

Comment: Updated link to 5.1 above.

Comment: I have tried the same one and its already installed on my machine

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online Management Shell requires PowerShell 3.0 installed:

[image]

Please install PowerShell 3.0 here:

[Windows Management Framework 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)

Comment: Thanks for helping but when I try to install this it says "The update is not applicable for your computer"

Comment: @RaviKhambhati, please check the fix from here for this error you are meeting:
https://mikefrobbins.com/2012/11/03/when-trying-to-install-powershell-version-3-0-you-receive-the-message-the-update-is-not-applicable-to-your-computer/

Comment: I have looked into the article but when I try to in stall .net framework it says I already have a newer version of the framework and couln't install.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar issue on Windows 10 machine. Windows 10 is using 5.1 and you can't force it to run 3.0. What works for me is to run CMD in Administrator then run the MSI installer from there. That shoule install SP Management Shell Successfully without requiring 3.0